# how to check if specific variables in a calendar/Date object match in java?

Tags: java, android, datetime

I have two Date objects which I have set using the calendar setTime() method, I need to check to determine whether or not the day matches but not the time, so for example

```
         //date1 is Sat Feb 17 20:49:54 +0000 2012
         //date2 is Sat Feb 17 10:39:58 +0000 2012

            cal1.setTime(date1);
            cal2.setTime(date2);
            if (calOld.equals(calNew)){

          }
```

I need the code to determine if Sat Feb 17 matches but ignore 20:49:54 +0000 2012, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the day of the year field to check if they are equal.

```
int day1 = cal1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
int day2 = cal2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
if(day1 == day2) {
   //Do whatever
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could use:

```
cal1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
cal1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
cal1.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
cal1.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
```

... and do the same with `cal2`. Then you should just be able to use `equals`.

Alternatively, if it doesn't add too much overhead to your application, you could use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) which has a *much* more sensible API. Then you can just use the `LocalDate` class, which represents a date with no time component :)

Comment: ah so this would change the values of all the times to 0 then?

Comment: @EdmundRojas: Yes. If you wanted to do it without changing the existing value, you'd want to copy it first.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a condition like this.. by comparing the day, month, year separately in a if condition like below:

```
    if(cal1.getMonth()==cal2.getMonth() && cal1.getDay()==cal2.getDay() && cal1.getYear()==cal2.getYear())
{
}
```

Comment: Those are all deprecated, just fyi

Answer (score 0):

There may be a better way:

```
if (cal1.get(Calender.DATE) == cal2.get(Calender.DATE) &&
    cal1.get(Calender.MONTH) == cal2.get(Calender.MONTH) &&
    cal1.get(Calender.YEAR) == cal2.get(Calender.YEAR)) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
public int compareDatePart(Calendar c1, Calendar c2) throws ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
    Date dpC1 = format.parse(format.format(c1));
    Date dpC2 = format.parse(format.format(c2));
    return dpC1.compareTo(dpC2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use truncate function: http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/time/DateUtils.html and compare it's results.